# java arraylists comparison A and B

Tags: java

I have two arraylists A and B in java. Arraylist A has duplicates but Arraylist B has unique and not all elements from arraylist A. I want to count the frequency of elements in arraylist A that are present in arraylist B

small example

```
A = {Red, Black, Red, Black, Green, Green, Brown, Black, Brown, Green}
B=  {Red, Brown, Green}
```

Result should be
Red =2, Brown= 2  Green = 3

Comment: You can start by taking a look at the `java.utils.Collections.frequency` method.

Comment: Collections.frequency seems to be slow. I want something that can do quickly for a log lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not replace list A with a Map<K, V> where K is the class type of the objects you have in A (such as String) and V is a Number such as Integer or Long. Then, instead of simply adding the same old values into A (when you construct the list in the first place), you would do this, for example:

```
Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
Integer currentCount = countMap.get("Red");
countMap.put("Red", (currentCount == null ? 1 : currentCount.intValue() + 1));
```

Then to get the counts of each object found in list B, you would just run through the map, checking each object from B one after the other:

```
List<String> listB = new List<String>();
listB.add("Red");
listB.add("Brown");
listB.add("Green");
for(String s : listB) {
    Integer quantityFoundInA = countMap.get(s);
    System.out.println("String <"+s"> found in list (map) 'A' "+(quantityFoundInA == null ? 0 : quantityFoundInA.intValue())+" times");
}
```

I'm guessing that this structure would be more efficient than simply storing multiple copies of the same objects in a List (so long as the objects you're storing in A are exactly the same if they share the same name).

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

```
    List<String> listA = Arrays.asList("Red", "Black", "Red", "Black", "Green", "Green", "Brown", "Black", "Brown", "Green");
    List<String> listB = Arrays.asList("Red", "Brown", "Green");

    for (String color : listB) {
        System.out.println(string + " " + Collections.frequency(listA, color));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think i did not frame my question well

Comment: I have given an example to make the question mo0re clear.  Any help is appreciated. Also i want a code well optimized and that can do quickly when there are large number of elements

Comment: Can you not at least _attempt_ this first?

Comment: I tried this:   List<String> p = new ArrayList<String>(ngrams);
                        p.retainAll(ugrams);
     
             for (String a : p) {
                 Integer freq = gramfrequency.get(a);
                 gramfrequency.put(a, (freq == null ? 1 : freq + 1));
       }    // this is taking hell lot of time for a big list

Comment: Collections.frequency is very slow anyway i will try again

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "MultiSet" interface in google guava:

```
MultiSet<String> multiSet = HashMultiSet.create(listA);
for (String s : listB) {
   multiSet.count(s);
}
```

You could always get better performance by storing your elements directly in the multiSet instead of a List.  But that depends on what else you want to do with it, since MultiSet implements the Collection interface, and not List.